# BDE administrator and Paradox 11

Tags: windows-10, bde, paradox

I've just upgraded from Windows 7 to windows 10. I used to use Paradox 5 with BDE administrator and things worked fine. However Paradox 5 didn't work with windows 10, so I upgraded it to Paradox 11. That's the context for what I'm going to ask next:

I'm trying to get Paradox to connect correctly to my BDE directory. I set a native configuration driver for paradox to a network folder through the BDE administrator, but when I open paradox and look in Settings>Preferences>BDE, the network control file directory is set to a generic folder C:\PROGRA~3\BORLAND\NETDIR\ instead of the network drive I defined in BDE administrator.

Is there some way to get this to work correctly, or force the network control file directory directly in Paradox? There's no options to edit it from the Preferences menu in the BDE subtab. I'm unable to use my queries unless this gets set correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way is to load the odapi/Idapi/bde configuration file from the icon you use to start paradox. This allows you to save a configuration which has the network path stored for the net directory

The command line option to add is E.g.
-o x:\yourpath\bde.cfg

Which points to the file you saved from the bde administrator.

I’m guessing your on 64 bit windows which causes a few issues for paradox. Basically the registry entries for bde are not in the expected place in 64 bit windows. There is also a slight problem in the it gets installed into program files x86. This can be fixed by a few Mklink commands to symbolic link to x86 folders to the program files folders.

Edit: forgot to add that paradox 5 is a 16 bit app which is why it does not work in 64 bit windows.

Comment: When I use the -o command on the filepath to the cfg file, I get this error: "An error was triggered in the 'saveCFG' method on an object of Session type.'  Yes, it's 64 bit. I tried to install paradox outside of the x86 folder, but it literally ignored the filepath I defined and installed it there anyways. I dunno if that was the installer or windows. How do I use mklink commands? is that an application or a windows operation? I've never heard of that before.

Comment: Whoops, I was using the wrong cfg file when I did that. I'm using the right one now and I'm not noticing any change in behavior with adding -o to .cfg file on the target field. My BDE directory is still "C:\PROGRA~3\...etc..."   I also looked into the mklink command. I made an mklink in my program files folder without the x86 and got a location not available error. So I moved it to just C:\Paradox, and the link is working, but I'm not noticing any difference in behavior as I use it. I added the -o to a shortcut to the C:\Paradox application and no difference, still C:\Progra~3\.

Comment: The format for mklink is 
mklink /d "C:\Program Files\Borland" "C:\Program Files (x86)\Borland"
mklink /d "C:\Program Files\Corel" "C:\Program Files (x86)\Corel"
depending upon what got installed. I'm using a combination of paradox 7 and 9

Comment: An example of the Target in an icon: 
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Borland\Paradox\PDXWIN32.EXE" -c -o t:\net\sql.cfg -w t:\wheelchr.db -p c:\db\%USERNAME%\w7.prv

Comment: sql.cfg above exist on the network share. -c clears the desktop. -w sets the working directory and -p sets the private directory

Comment: -o just points paradox to config file. The net dir needs to be set within that file to a network share if you want to have multiuser access to a paradox table on a network share. The actual file path of the cfg file and the BDE folder is meaningless as long as paradox can access them. If you are not needing multiuser access then setting BDE to a network share will be unnecessary.

Comment: I was able to generate a new .cfg file from scratch and load that in. Once it was in place the network control file directory updated correctly and I was able to load and run my queries. I'm thinking maybe something in the .cfg file got corrupt when updating from window7 to window10? I see what you're saying about clearing, working directory, etc, but I think I can avoid having to do that.